# Deploying an XBAP with ClickOnce. Why should I do that?

Tags: deployment, xbap

In the book *MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-502): Microsoft® .NET Framework 3.5 Windows® Presentation Foundation* there is a topic about XBAP deployment using ClickOnce. I’ve discussed with some colleagues and all said that it doesn’t make any sense. So why is in the book XBAP deployment with ClickOnce covered? I think there must be a basic reason but honestly I don’t get it. What do you trink?